# Selecting data from 2 different tables depending upon the conditions; mySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have 2 tables; table A and table B

Table A has 3 columns; a, b, c
Table B has 2 columns; d and e

I want to select 
IF A.b is NOT NULL THEN SELECT A.b
ELSE IF A.b IS NULL THEN SELECT B.d

any help please

I just made up this example, but if required then say A.a and A.c  are unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try!

// select data from your database

Select * From TABLE_A

```
if((A.a != "") || (A.a != NULL)){

 // select d from table B


} else {

// echo records from your column B 

}
```

Comment: It did not work. But I have found a work around to solve this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Amit thanks so much for describing your workaround. :(